# MboxIterator not in Apache Mime4J

Tags: java, apache, parsing, mbox, mime4j

I downloaded the binaries of the latest stable version of `apache-mime4j` (0.7.2).

Yet, I fail to compile the next code since `MboxIterator` & `CharBufferWrapper` classes are not found.

```
final File mbox = new File("path/name.mbox");
for (CharBufferWrapper message : MboxIterator.fromFile(mbox).charset(ENCODER.charset()).build()) 
{do something}
```

The jars included in my build path: `apache-mime4j-core-0.7.2.jar`, `apache-mime4j-dom-0.7.2.jar`.

Am I using the wrong jars or version?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I ended getting it to work by doing a little research.

The classes you mention, at least by what I found, are not included into Mime4J, so you have to code them yourself. Thanks to the devs, they got them uploaded in the following link: [MBoxIterator needed classes](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/james/mime4j/trunk/mbox/src/main/java/org/apache/james/mime4j/mboxiterator/).

Hope those solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the current snaphshot of the mime4j project from

- http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/james/mime4j/trunk/

to your personal github account

or use my clone:

- https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/james-mime4j

and your MBoxIterator is here:

- https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/james-mime4j/tree/trunk/mbox/src/main/java/org/apache/james/mime4j/mboxiterator